# Question about Distributive Laws of Logic and proof of the Symmetric Difference

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Here is the definition of the Symmetric Difference:
$$
A \Delta B = (A \backslash B) \cup (B \backslash A),
$$
Our goal is to prove:
$$
A \Delta B = (A \cup B) \backslash(A \cap B).
$$

I want to prove this and at the same time to check if my understanding of the Distributive Laws of Logic is correct.

**My main goal is about Distributive Laws of Logic. I want to know if I can always break the parenthesis with this method.**

***I know that there are similar proofs in the website but I feel that I need help with the Distributive Laws.***

Please check if this is correct:

We start with

$(x \in A$ $\land$ $x \notin  B)$ $\vee$ $(x \notin A$ $\land$ $x \in  B)$

***This is the part that I want to know if I am correct, and I want to know if I can do this for any parenthesis regarding of what is inside of the parenthesis of the right part:***

$(x \in A$ $\land$ $x \notin  B)$ $\vee$ x $\notin$ A ) $\land$

$(x \in A$ $\land$ $x \notin  B)$ $\vee$ x $\in$ B )

***Now we can use the classic version of the Distributive Law:***

$(x \in A$ $\vee$ x $\notin$ $A$ ) $\land$

$(x \notin B$ $\vee$ x $\notin$ $A$ ) $\land$

$(x \in A$ $\vee$ x $\in$ $B$ ) $\land$

$(x \notin B$ $\vee$ x $\in$ $B$ )

***Now we can simplify:***

******Universe****** $\land$

$(x \notin B$ $\vee$ x $\notin$ $A$ ) $\land$

$(x \in A$ $\vee$ x $\in$ $B$ ) $\land$

******Universe******

***Finally we have,***

$(x \in A$ $\vee$ x $\in$ $B$ ) $\land$

$(x \notin B$ $\vee$ x $\notin$ $A$ )

***The last step is to use the Morgan Laws***

$(x \in A$ $\vee$ x $\in$ $B$ ) $\land$

$\neg$ $(x \in A$ $\land$ $x$ $\in$ $B$ )

That is our goal:

[image: Goal]

***Q.E.D.***

Comment: I just happened to see this!  I suppose 'pinging' me in a comment to your own question does not work ... anyway, yes, your proof is fine! And yes, you can use Distribution on part of a statement just as you are using DeMorgan on just part of the statement in your last step.

Comment: @Bram28 Thank you so much again for your amazing teachings!

Comment: You're welcome!  And by the way, I definitely see your progress with this material!! :)

Comment: @Bram28 I have been using your teachings about Latex and Mathematical Logic. You are fantastic! Thank you so much!

Comment: :) I appreciate your kind words ... but *you* are doing the learning!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is a permissible application of distribution.

It is basically using the proof for the quadratic distribution: $$(s\wedge t)\vee (u\wedge v)~{= (s\vee (u\wedge v))\wedge(t\vee (u\wedge v))\\ =(s\vee u)\wedge(s\vee v)\wedge(t\vee u)\wedge (t\vee v)}$$

> Take an arbitrary $x$ such that $x\in (S\cap T)\cup(U\cap V)$.   By definition of union and disjunction, this is equivalent to $(x\in S\wedge x\in T)\vee(x\in U\wedge x\in V)$.   By distribution, that is equivalent to $(x\in S\vee(x\in U\wedge x\in V))\wedge (x\in T\vee(x\in U\wedge x\in V))$, and distributing again that is $(x\in S\vee x\in U)\wedge (x\in S\vee x\in V)\wedge (x\in T\vee x\in U)\wedge (x\in T\vee x\in V)$. Thus it is equivalent to $x\in(S\cup U)\cap (S\cup V)\cap (T\cup U)\cap (T\cup V)$.

More succinctly, using the set algebra:

$$(S\cap T)\cup(U\cap V)~{=(S\cup(U\cap V))\cap(T\cup(U\cap V))\\=(S\cup U)\cap (S\cup V)\cap (T\cup U)\cap (T\cup V)}$$

Just substitute the relevant sets.

---

If we presume complementation relative to some superset $\mathcal U$ (the "universe") of both $A,B$, then your proof is essentially:

$$\def\sm{\smallsetminus} {\begin{align}
&\quad (A\Delta B)
\\ &= (A\sm B)\cup(B\sm A) &&\text{definition of symmetric difference}
\\& = (A\cap B^\complement)\cup(B\cap A^\complement) &&\text{definition of set minus}
\\& = (A\cup (B\cap A^\complement))\cap(B^\complement\cup (B\cap A^\complement)) && \text{distribution}
\\& = (A\cup B)\cap(A\cup A^\complement)\cap (B^\complement\cup B)\cap (B^\complement\cup A^\complement)&&\text{distribution}
\\& = (A\cup B)\cap\mathcal U\cap\mathcal U\cap (B^\complement\cup A^\complement)&&\text{complementation}
\\&=  (A\cup B)\cap(B^\complement\cup A^\complement) && \text{identity}
\\&=  (A\cup B)\cap(A^\complement\cup B^\complement) && \text{commutivity}
\\&= (A\cup B)\cap(A\cap B)^\complement & & \text{deMorgan's Rule}
\\&= (A\cup B)\sm(A\cap B) && \text{definition of set minus}\end{align}}$$

Comment: Thank you so much! Amazing answer! I like very much the idea to treat the problem with Set Laws. In that way, the solution can be reduced to few steps.

Comment: I am using your teaching to apply set rules instead of logic rules and it reduces the work to be done at least 50%. Thank you so much!